# ruby float parse

Tags: ruby, floating-point

like a float:

```
if i == 2.0 i want to get: 2
if i == 2.3 or 2.23 i want to get: 2.3 or 2.23
```

Comment: Are you talking about string output or something else?

Answer (score 4):

Use this expression. Just insert it wherever you want the result:

```
i.to_i == i ? i.to_i : i
```